# Using Swi-Prolog in emacs shell

Tags: emacs, swi-prolog

Is there a way to get emacs shell mode to play nice with SWI-Prolog? For example if I run `M-x shell` then `swipl` I get into Prolog okay but if I for example query `?-member(X,[1,2,3,4]).` I get `X=1` however I can not interact with this in the normal way e.g. I can't press SPACE to backtrack. I can type `;` then ENTER to get one back track result and I can even type `;;;` to get 3 results but I don't know how to interact with this shell in the normal way. i.e see a result and then ask for more results.

Comment: `shell-mode` is a wrapper around an external shell. It doesn't try to send each keypress transparently. Try `M-x term` which does attempt to do this

Comment: If you use `C-c C-l` from the prolog-mode buffer, you'll get into a SWI prolog interactive session which should behave like you expect.

Comment: `C-c C-l` does not work for me (undefined) but `M-x` term does thanks. I also found I could start swipl with `-tty` option in the shell to get a usable solution by typing `;` followed by `enter`.